# Scala List: Why does this List operation work?

Tags: scala, list, covariance

given that the full signature of :: is as follows
  `::[B >: A](x: B): List[B`]

then why does this example work?

```
class Fruit(name: String) { }
class Orange(name: String) extends Fruit(name)
class BigOrange(name:String) extends Orange(name)

 val f = new Fruit("fruit")
 val a = new Apple("apple")
 val o = new Orange("orange")
 val bo = new BigOrange("big orange")

 val oList :List[Orange] = List[Orange](o,o) 
 val fList1: List[Fruit] = f::oList
 val fList2: List[Fruit] = a::oList
 val  oList2 :List[Orange] = bo::oList // works, but why?
```

all works and compiles...but why does the last line even work? Does'nt the signature above say that it only works if supertype of orange  is appended?

I get it that a BigOrange is an Orange, so it would seem to make intuitive sense that a list of oranges is able to add a BigOrange.  But the signature: it explicitly seems to disallow that operation

Comment: Type checker searches for proofs of definitions. And there is one because `BigOrange` is the `Orange` (via inheritance).

Comment: What does B >: A mean? Does it not mean that " the passed argument of Type B needs to have a path down to Type A"? or does it mean "if the passed argument can be treated as  some X, and that X has a path to A"? I am confused

Comment: @user7938511 `B >: A` means "B is a superclass of A" (where the "superclass" relation is both transitive and reflexive) and `x: B` means "the argument `x` is of type `B` or one of its subtypes". You can always assign a subtype to given variable or parameter - regardless of generics.

Comment: @user7938511 it means type or its super type. sepp2k already explained correctly.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`<:` and `>:` are reflexive, that is every type is a sub and supertype of itself.

So introducing `B >: A` as the type of the prepended item does not disallow values of type `A`.

Comment: but here BigOrange was passed. why would  BigOrange  satisfy X >: Orange

Comment: @user7938511 `B` is `Orange`. If you wanted the result to be a `List[BigOrange]`, then `B` would have to be `BigOrange`, which is impossible. But the result is `List[Orange]`, so it all works out. So `::` takes an `Orange` as a parameter and it's always legal to pass a `BigOrange` to a method that accepts an `Orange`.